# Interdependent filters applied to datatable in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

In the following reproducible example I have created a datatable that can be sorted out according to the **"field_of_study"** filter (the other filters are not set-up).

Now I would like to improve this example by enabling the other filters in order to make them interdependant (filter 1 would filter the table AND the others filters).

I already used [shinyfilter](https://github.com/jsugarelli/shinyfilter) for other purposes but it doesn't suit to the current example since the columns `field_of_study` and `skills` contains concatenated values I want to be able to pick-up in my filter...

What is the best way to do that please ?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(stringr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dataset <- data.frame("person" = c('personA', 'personA','personA', 'personA','personB','personB','personB','personC','personC','personD','personE'),
                      "location" = c('ER1','ER1','ER1','ER1','QF5','QF5','QF5','BV9','BV9','ER1','ER3'),
                      "field_of_study" = c('Genetics','Biochemistry','Ecophysiology','Phylogeny','Ecology','GIS', 'Ecotoxicology', 'Genetics', 'Ecology', 'GIS', 'Geology'),
                      "skills" = c('G01','B04','EC04','P02','E02','G01', 'E07', 'G01', 'E07', 'G02', 'G08'))


dataset  <- dataset %>% 
  group_by(person, location) %>% 
  summarise(field_of_study=paste(unique(field_of_study), collapse = " - "),
            skills=paste(skills, collapse = " - "))


ui = fluidPage(
      actionButton(inputId = "filter",label = "Filter"),
         DT::dataTableOutput("skills_directory"))


server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_directory <- reactiveValues(data=dataset)
  
  output$skills_directory <-  DT::renderDataTable({

    DT::datatable(isolate(data_directory$data), 
                  selection = 'single',
                  rownames = FALSE, 
                  editable = FALSE,
                  options = list(dom = 't'))
              })
  
  
    observeEvent(input$filter,{
    showModal(fluidRow(align="center",
                       modalDialog(title = "Critères de recherche :",
                                   selectizeInput("person", "Person", choices = c('', dataset$person), multiple = TRUE),
                                   selectizeInput("location", "Location", choices = c('', dataset$location), multiple = TRUE),
                                   selectizeInput("field_of_study", "Fields of study", selected ='', choices = c('', unlist(str_extract_all(dataset$field_of_study,"\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*"), recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)), multiple = TRUE),
                                   selectizeInput("skills", "Skills", choices = c('', unlist(str_extract_all(dataset$skills,"\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*"), recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)), multiple = TRUE),
                                   actionButton(inputId = "search",label = "Search"),
                                   footer = tagList(
                                     modalButton("Annuler")
                                   ), easyClose = TRUE, 
                                   size = "l", 
                                   fade = TRUE)
                                   ))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$search,{
    
    data_directory <- reactiveValues(data=dataset)
    
    selected <- reactive({
      if (length(input$field_of_study != 0)) { stringr::str_detect(data_directory$data$field_of_study, fixed(input$field_of_study, ignore_case=TRUE))} 
      else {TRUE}
    })
    
    data_directory$data <- data_directory$data[selected(),] 
    
    proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy('skills_directory')
    
    DT::replaceData(proxy,  data_directory$data, rownames = FALSE)
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `observe` to track changes in selectize inputs then filter the database and update the choices.
I did that for the "field_of_study" column.
The fact that every cell has multiple values to be matched make it tedious to do for every column, also when you update the choices, the box containing the choices is invalidated and closed, which does'n help to the user experience.

The "canonical" way would be [selectizeGroupUI](https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/reference/selectizeGroup-module.html), which do exactly what you want however I think it does not work with your dataset (because the multiple choices).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(stringr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
  
dataset <- data.frame("person" = c('personA', 'personA','personA', 'personA','personB','personB','personB','personC','personC','personD','personE'),
                      "location" = c('ER1','ER1','ER1','ER1','QF5','QF5','QF5','BV9','BV9','ER1','ER3'),
                      "field_of_study" = c('Genetics','Biochemistry','Ecophysiology','Phylogeny','Ecology','GIS', 'Ecotoxicology', 'Genetics', 'Ecology', 'GIS', 'Geology'),
                      "skills" = c('G01','B04','EC04','P02','E02','G01', 'E07', 'G01', 'E07', 'G02', 'G08'))



dataset  <- dataset %>% 
  group_by(person, location) %>% 
  summarise(field_of_study=paste(unique(field_of_study), collapse = " - "),
            skills=paste(skills, collapse = " - "))


ui = fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "filter",label = "Filter"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("skills_directory"))


server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_directory <- reactiveValues(data=dataset)
  
  output$skills_directory <-  DT::renderDataTable({
    
    DT::datatable(isolate(data_directory$data), 
                  selection = 'single',
                  rownames = FALSE, 
                  editable = FALSE,
                  options = list(dom = 't'))
  })
  
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$field_of_study)){
      dataset<- dataset %>% filter(
        map_lgl(field_of_study, ~ any(unlist(str_extract_all(.,"\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*")) %in% input$field_of_study)))}
      updateSelectizeInput(session,"person", choices = c('', dataset$person))
      updateSelectizeInput(session,"location", choices = c('', dataset$location))
      updateSelectizeInput(session,"skills",  choices = c('', unlist(str_extract_all(dataset$skills,"\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*"), recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)))
    })
    

  observeEvent(input$filter,{
    
    showModal(fluidRow(align="center",
                       modalDialog(title = "Critères de recherche :",
                                   selectizeInput("person", "Person", choices = c('', dataset$person), multiple = TRUE),
                                   selectizeInput("location", "Location", choices = c('', dataset$location), multiple = TRUE),
                                   selectizeInput("field_of_study", "Fields of study", selected ='', choices = c('', unlist(str_extract_all(dataset$field_of_study,"\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*"), recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)), multiple = TRUE),
                                   selectizeInput("skills", "Skills", choices = c('', unlist(str_extract_all(dataset$skills,"\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*"), recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)), multiple = TRUE),
                                   actionButton(inputId = "search",label = "Search"),
                                   footer = tagList(
                                     modalButton("Annuler")
                                   ), easyClose = TRUE, 
                                   size = "l", 
                                   fade = TRUE)
    ))
  
  }) 
  
  
  observeEvent(input$search,{
    
    data_directory <- reactiveValues(data=dataset)
    
    selected <- reactive({
      if (length(input$field_of_study != 0)) { stringr::str_detect(data_directory$data$field_of_study, fixed(input$field_of_study, ignore_case=TRUE))} 
      else {TRUE}
    })
    
    data_directory$data <- data_directory$data[selected(),] 
    
    proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy('skills_directory')
    
    DT::replaceData(proxy,  data_directory$data, rownames = FALSE)
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ricardo but as you said it yourself : it doesn't match my need since I can't really do that for every column and I can't use selectizeGroupUI :(

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it is not the cleanest solution but you could (in addition of Ric Villalba's answer) create 4 reactive expressions based on your input to subset your `data_directory$data`

```
selected <- reactive({
  if (length(input$field_of_study != 0)) { stringr::str_detect(data_directory$data$field_of_study, fixed(input$field_of_study, ignore_case=TRUE))} 
  else {TRUE}
})

selected2 <- reactive({
  if (length(input$person != 0)) { stringr::str_detect(data_directory$data$person, fixed(input$person, ignore_case=TRUE))} 
  else {TRUE}
})

selected3 <- reactive({
  if (length(input$location != 0)) { stringr::str_detect(data_directory$data$location, fixed(input$location, ignore_case=TRUE))} 
  else {TRUE}
})

selected4 <- reactive({
  if (length(input$skills != 0)) { stringr::str_detect(data_directory$data$skills, fixed(input$skills, ignore_case=TRUE))} 
  else {TRUE}
})

        
data_directory$data <- data_directory$data[selected(),] 
data_directory$data <- data_directory$data[selected2(),] 
data_directory$data <- data_directory$data[selected3(),] 
data_directory$data <- data_directory$data[selected4(),]
```